# Interactive merge with SVN to merge commit by commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, interactive

Do you know any tool that support the followings:

- eclipse integration (not mandatory)
- merge tracking
- interactive merge
- merging with selecting changesets, but commit them one-by-one to preserve commit comments

So the flow I expect:

- picking the source to merge to workspace
- choosing revisions to merge
- the program would do the merge for the first revision, would pop up conflict resolving if any, and if no conflict it would commit with the original commit comment + merging info with appropiate svn properties
- go to next revision.

Do you know such tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I doubt any tool does this exactly as you describe - why would they when you can a) replicate the functionality by merging 1 revision at a time anyway, b) prefer to make the commit a manual process so the operator can check the merged results. Having merges commit automatically is just slightly optimistic.

You could write such a tool with script - for each revision, merge, fetch original log comment, commit.

Note you don't need to worry about properties as they are merged automatically as part of the merge process.